# Systemctl(?) killing detached screens

Tags: linux, go, service, systemd, gnu-screen

I have a program written in Go that programmatically creates and manages screens. Here's an example:

```golang
_, err := exec.Command("screen", "-S", "screen-"+strings.ToLower(name), "-X", "stuff", command+"\n").Output()
```

This works fine. When I Control+C the program, the screens created stay open (what I want!). However, I've converted it into a background service on Ubuntu. When I run `systemctl stop <service>`, it kills those screens without a warning. Attaching to a screen doesn't stop this either (instantly goes to `[screen terminated]`). It doesn't kill screens created externally, however.

Here is my `.service`:

```
[Unit]
Description=>servicename> background service
After=network-online.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/lib/<servicename>/service

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

My `rules`:

```
%:
    dh $@ --with systemd --parallel

override_dh_auto_install:
    dh_auto_install
    dh_systemd_enable || true
    dh_systemd_start || true
```

My `control`:

```
Package: <name>
Version: 0.2
Architecture: amd64
Priority: optional
Maintainer: <me>
Description: <description>
Depends: screen, iptables
Build-Depends: dh-systemd (>=1.5)
```

I can't imagine what would cause these screens to kill. I'm pretty sure they're not being attached in the program because it runs fine as an executable. System logs don't mention anything outside of "service stopped' and 'service started'. I've tried making screens under root, different users, running an empty screen vs running a program, etc. Nothing notable.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`systemd` by default kills all processes (screens) if the main service that created them (your Go program) exits. Note this is not only subprocesses but any processes within the same cgroup. This is to make sure that if service crashes there are no leftover processes from it.

This behavior can be controlled using key `KillMode=` in `.service` unit file which is described [here](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.kill.html). Although not recommended you need to set it to either `process` or `none` (to leave your screens unmanaged and escape your service lifecycle management by `systemd`).